# Unity + ARKit / Make object stay in place after image tracking

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to make an object spawn with the `ARKit` image tracking.

But once it has spawned, I want to forget the image anchor (If the image disappears, the object is still here).

I managed to find a way of doing it insofar as `GenerateImageAnchor.UpdateImageAnchor()`, however, the object is not independent anymore of the image.

But it now follows the `ARCamera`.

How can I "fix" its position so that now that once it has spawned and is `independant`, it stays in place so that we can move around the scene and it will stay at the same position?

Comment: Your spawning object is attached to/his parent is..?

Comment: @Lotan The object is automatically instantiated in the ARKit class "GenerateImageAnchor". I just logged the parent when the object appears and it doesn't have any

Comment: and which mode has your ARCamera? World Center Mode?

Comment: There is no mode for ARCamera in ARKit. I've only seen it when using Vuforia.

Comment: Hey I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?